# How should I accept this text file when I am running Python from command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, file-io

This is the way that the program will be run:
`Python LinkState < test1.txt`
`Linkstate` is the name of the .py file. test1.txt is the name of the text file being accepted in the python code.
So my question is how should I handle the txt file in my code for this to work?

I assume this is a Windows format. I am a mac user, I don't have bootcamp installed and I don't want it. Is there anyway I can test on my mac to make sure this will work in the windows environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the way the command is setup is using soemthing called IO redirection which is a construct that is more inline with Unix-like systems than Windows for reasons I won't get into here (I would defer to this great [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141016/a-laymans-explanation-for-everything-is-a-file-what-differs-from-windows) here for a detailed comparison. Also google 'Everything is a file Unix' for more concise summary).

Since macOS is a Unix-like system, IO redirection is a very natural thing to do. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366763/input-redirection-with-python) here gives a concise answer to deal with that. Also refer to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin) for processing stdin.